# Checking dynamic button pressed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am learning VB.Net at college and I am trying to find a way to check the button clicked by the user in vb.net form. The problem I am currently having is that I have an array of 10x10 buttons, created dynamically in the code.

```
 For x = 1 To 10
        For y = 1 To 10
            Me.Width = 720
            Me.Height = 720

            boxarray(counter) = New Button
            boxarray(counter).Name = "Box" & x
            boxarray(counter).Location = New Point(x * 48, y * 48)
            boxarray(counter).Width = Me.Width / 15
            boxarray(counter).Height = Me.Height / 15
            boxarray(counter).Visible = True
            boxarray(counter).Cursor = Cursors.Hand
            boxarray(counter).PerformClick()
            Me.Controls.Add(boxarray(counter))
            counter = counter + 1
           Next
        Next
```

However I need to check the button that the user has clicked, without needing to create subroutines for each individual button, that could be pressed.

Comment: PS are you sure you want to do this? One Image of something that looks like 100 buttons and some mouse event handlers would do the bulk of it in most cases.

Comment: The purpose of this program, was to make a mini-game similar to that of "Candy Crush". I was using buttons as a way to act as each of the blocks for people to click on to change the block locations. So the image would constantly need to change for the program to work :)

Comment: Surprisingly I'd considered that might be the case. You can invalidate part of a control, so in terms of painting you wouldn't have to redraw all 100 buttons each time one changed. It's much of muchness code wise, more actual code less scaffolding, where you score is things like responsive painting of the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add a Handler

e.g.

```
Private Sub ArrayButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Handle your Button clicks here
End Sub
```

Then change `boxarray(counter).PerformClick()` (which simuates clicking the button)
to

```
AddHandler boxarray(counter), AddressOf ArrayButton_Click
```

Now all your buttons are linked to one handler.
Course now you need to know which one was clicked.
Setting the tag property to ((x - 1) * 10) + y - 1 would be one way

Then you could cast sender to Button. Grab the tag and convert it back to x and y in the handler

Comment: stop after `cast the sender to Button`

Comment: Simpler way is to name your buttons names, "Box" + ((x - 1) * 10 + y).ToString.  From here after you cast sender as a Button(Dim CurrentButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)), CurrentButton.Name.Substring(3) will return the number of the button

Comment: Certainly a possibility, especially seeing as you'd want to give them unique names for say automation testing in the real world